# mailtrap connection error laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to test send mail using laravel 5.3 I'm using mailable. But I'm getting this error: `Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110]`

My env config is:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I also cleared cache using:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

But still not working.

Comment: have you tried restarting `Apache`?

Comment: try with port 2525

Comment: tried that as well.

Comment: Could it be in your `config/mail.php`? This works for me, both for mailtrap on dev as on the live server `'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',`. Your config seems to be ok. If not, there is an issue on your testing server. What do you use?

Comment: still not working @DimitriMostrey

Comment: Then I suspect your testing environment.

Comment: Only for my knowledge and out of curiosity, why are you using 465 as `MAIL_PORT` and not the default `2525` that is shipped with Laravel?

Comment: I tried both the 465 and 2525 @SaiyanPrince

Comment: Once you make changes in your `.env` file, you need to restart your application once again so that it takes the value from the edited environment file. Have you tried restarting the application?

Comment: Thanks @SaiyanPrince. I restarted the ngnix server. Now it's working.

Comment: @BhagyashreeSarkar you're most welcome..